# Generate samples of sinusoid in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to generate 100 samples of sinusoid in matlab with frequency 0.2Hz and sampling rate 2Hz. Until now i have pass into matlab the values:

```
>> t=[0:99];
>> f=0.2;
>> fs=2;
```

The sin-wave function is this:

$y(t)=A*sin(2pft+φ)$

Does the Amplitude has some connection with the sampling rate? For example Amplitude values start from 0 and with step of 0.2 did i need to take 100 samples? And how i could find φ in order to plot this signal?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/changing-audio-sampling-rate.html look at this

Comment: now your task is to determine what should be upper index so that,total number be 100

Comment: i will give you  code in a few minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate
Amplitude is generally independent of sampling rate,about  phase shift you can omit it now,because  actually finding this parameters or  method called frequency estimation are many,you can search it on internet

```
>> f=0.2;
>> fs=2;
>> A=100;%suppose that amplitude is 100
>> q=20;
>> t=0:1/fs:49;
>> x=A*sin(2*pi*f*t+q);
total length is 101,1 more then you want
```

Comment: Thank you, so if the amplitude is independent and i can omit the phase then is it correct if i write to matlab: y(t)= sin(2pft)/fs  ?

Comment: phase you can write yourself,but i think you should divide  by fs not outside,but inside,it means that y(t)=sin(2*pi*f/fs+phase shift),ask to stackoverflow and then please give me link of your  question ok?

Comment: if you would like i will ask it to stackoverflow exactly how it should look and post here  if any change ok?

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Comment: You use this: "t = 0:1/Fs:1-(1/Fs);" to generate: "t=0:1/fs:49;" ? Or because i need 100 samples? I dont understand the formula you use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508782/generate-100-sample-at-given-rate  see this,i have asked it and now we get both exact answer

Comment: yes it is i used .just i have determined upper limit

Comment: see please answer,it was posted

Comment: You are correct choosing the right method! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: you are welcome  good lucks